# Calculate Sharpe ratio for only one return

Tags: sharpe-ratio, performance-evaluation

I have only one return for calculating sharp ratio. As you know, we should calculate standard deviation of returns and standard deviation of one item is 0. Suppose that the single return is 0.1 and the risk less return is 0.2. How can I calculate sharp ratio for these two inputs?

Comment: Clearly you can't. One way would be to look at similar asset which is correlated with yours and use that asset's volatility to calculate SR.

Comment: @rbm.  I'm designing a trading system winch optimizes different parameters to generate buy and sell signals. In some severe cases, there is only one buy and sell signal, so I have only one return. What do you think about this case? The Sharpe ratio is my cost function in this system so I can't ignore it in this special case.

Comment: Personally I'd not handle this case at all, as it looks like you're describing an asset in highly illiquid market. Obviously I do not know all the details but sounds like I wouldn't even produce a signal

Comment: if you have only one buy and sell signal for a period of say 100 days theb your strategy has many 0 returns and the returns caused by the signal.

Comment: @Richard. Can you elaborate this more? What is your idea for handing this problem? As mentioned, this is cost function of my algorithm.

Comment: the question as it is makes no sense. If you just have one realisation of a return then you can not calculate SR from it. If you have a strategy that is pplied to a time series of say 100 returns and you only invest once then your strategy return is not just one return.

Comment: user2991243 - @Richard 's point is that in an illiquid market, the price is effectively stale, i.e. it's 100 today and 100 tomorrow, making the return zero. If there are no price changes in 100 days, (i.e. price stays at 100), then you simply have 99 zero-returns. Makes sense?

Comment: No, I don't mean that even with a liquid asset if it has 100 returns different from zero, then for say the first 50 days if you don't have a signal - you are not in the market and the return of your strategy is 0. Then you trade and enter long, then you get the return of the asset. You have to look at the product return*holding. But as we discuss that much: please reformulate the question to make clear what you mean!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single period return, the squared value of that return approximates variance (i.e., the absolute value approximates the standard deviation).

Standard deviation is defined thus:

$$\sigma_X = \sqrt\frac{\Sigma_1^N\mathbb{E}[X-\mu_x]^2}{N}$$

For a non-drifting process, $\mu_x = 0$. Also, in our scenario, $X = (r_a - r_m)$ and $N = 1$.

Therefore, an approximation of the Sharpe ratio should be:

$$S = \frac{r_a-r_b}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[r_a-r_m]^2}} \approx \frac{r_a-r_m}{\mid r_a-r_b\mid} $$

Using $r_a = .1$ and $r_b = .2$, $S$ should equal $-1$.

If you need annualize the returns or standard deviation, just remember that logarithmic returns scale with $T$ and logarithmic standard deviation *should* scale with $\sqrt{T}$. If operating under the assumption that returns are percentages, one must convert these into logarithmic returns first and/or use geometric compounding rules.

For a related thread see: [Why is $dS/S$ an estimate of realized volatility?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33372/why-is-ds-s-an-estimate-of-realized-volatility#comment46604_33372)

Addendum: A perhaps pertinent point that I missed in my original pass through is that the [mean absolute error is related to the expected standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) by a factor of ${\sqrt {2/\pi }}=0.79788456\ldots$, i.e.,

> For the normal distribution, the ratio of mean absolute deviation to
>   expected standard error is:
>   $w=\frac{ E|X| }{ \sqrt{E(X^2)} } = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.

Furthermore, the [median absolute error is connected with standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation#Relation_to_standard_deviation) by the following:

> ${\displaystyle {\hat {\sigma }}=k\cdot \operatorname {MAD} ,\,}$
>   where k is a constant scale factor, which depends on the
>   distribution.
>
> For normally distributed data k is taken to be:
>
> ${\displaystyle k=1/\left(\Phi ^{-1}(3/4)\right)\approx 1.4826}$

Therefore, one could improve the estimate of the single-sample Sharpe ratio by multiplying it by $\approx [.67,\, .8]$. Both answers seem like the right one, unless of course, one argues that sample moments are undefined for a single sample space.